# Solving for argument of complete elliptic integral of first kind

Tags: problem-solving, rational-functions, elliptic-integrals

I have the following equation to be solved for $m$

$\frac{K(1-m)}{K(m)} = a$

where $a$ is known value, $K(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind. $K(m)$ can be expressed as an infinite series which I found on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

I don't know how to go about solving this equation.

Comment: Numerical solution is one way

Answer (score 1):

If

$$ f(m) := \frac{K(1-m)}{K(m)}, \tag{1}$$
then
$$ f(m) = -\frac{\log(q(m))}{\pi} \tag{2}$$
where $\, q(m) \equiv q(k^2) \,$ is the
[Jacobi elliptic nome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nome_(mathematics)) $\,q\,$ defined as

$$ q(m) := e^{-\pi K(1-m)/K(m)} =
  e^{-\pi f(m)}. \tag{3} $$

Given $\, f(m), \,$ to find $\, m, \,$ use equation
$\,(3)\,$ to compute $\, q(m). \,$ Then
$$ m = \frac{ \theta_2(0,q)^4} {\theta_3(0,q)^4} =
16q - 128q^2 + 704q^3 +\dots \tag{4} $$
where $\,\theta_2, \, \theta_3\,$ are [Jacobi theta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_theta_functions_(notational_variations)).
The[OEIS sequence A115977](http://oeis.org/A115977)
has more information about the $q$ series expansion
of $m$.

As a numerical example, assume $\,f(m) = 1.6.\,$ Then
$$   \theta_2 \approx 0.569243 , \,
 \theta_3 \approx 1.013123 , \,
 q \approx 0.0065614, \\
 16q - 128q^2 + 740q^3 \approx 0.0996652, \,
 m \approx 0.0996653.$$

Comment: This did not work for me, I am going to use a numerical approach - a binary search maybe.

Comment: @Tej I have corrected equation 4.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a problem I worked years ago and I give you some old results of mine.*

As said in answer and comments, you will need some numerical methods and, for sure, a guess of the solution.

If we use a very limited series expansion built around $m=0$, we have
$$\frac{K(1-m)}{K(m)}=\frac 1 {2 \pi} \left(8\log(2)-2\log(m)-m \right)+O\left(m^2\right)$$ from which $$m=2 W\left(8 e^{-\pi a}\right)\tag 1$$ where appears Lambert function. This is quite good for $a >1$ as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  a  & (1) & \text{exact} \\
 1.0 & 0.530366 &  0.500000 \\
 1.1 & 0.411170 &  0.396910 \\
 1.2 & 0.315098 &  0.308663 \\
 1.3 & 0.239066 &  0.236256 \\
 1.4 & 0.179861 &  0.178666 \\
 1.5 & 0.134392 &  0.133894 \\
 1.6 & 0.099869 &  0.099665 \\
 1.7 & 0.073898 &  0.073816 \\
 1.8 & 0.054501 &  0.054468 \\
 1.9 & 0.040096 &  0.040083 \\
 2.0 & 0.029442 &  0.029437
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If you are only concerned by the case $a < 1$, we can build the $[3,3]$ Padé approximant built at $m=\frac 12$,we should get
$$\frac{K(1-m)}{K(m)}=\frac{1+b_1 \left(m-\frac 12\right)+b_2\left(m-\frac 12\right)^2+b_3\left(m-\frac 12\right)^3}{1-b_1 \left(m-\frac 12\right)+b_2\left(m-\frac 12\right)^2-b_3\left(m-\frac 12\right)^3}$$ where
$$b_1=\frac{\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}\qquad b_2=-\frac{32}{15}\qquad b_3=\frac{1275 \pi  \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{2048 \sqrt{2} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{13}{4}\right)}$$ and solve a cubic equation in $\left(m-\frac 12\right)$. This seems to give acceptable results for $0.5 \leq a \leq 1$.

Comment: I need a closed form solution or approximation for $a<1$, till I find such a solution I am relying on binary search.