# Quotient of quarter periods K' and K of Jacobi elliptic functions

Tags: elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

There are several ways to express the quarter period $K$,
$$
K(m)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2\theta}},
$$
as a power series (and thus for $K'=K(1-m)$ there are, too) and also efficient ways of calculation (like agm).
But are there any known formulas for the *quotient*
$$
K'/K
$$
? I'm new to the field of elliptic functions.

Any ideas, general results etc.?

Comment: My answer to [MSE question 2932105](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2932105) "Solving for argument of complete elliptic integral of first kind" may answer your question here.

Comment: Okay thanks, at least my Taylor expansion is faulty...

Comment: Your expansion is quite interesting, how did you get it?

Comment: $\frac{K(1-m)}{K(m)}=\frac 1 {2 \pi} \left(8\log(2)-2\log(m)-m \right)+O\left(m^2\right)$ I mean

Comment: Using the [Wolfram Cloud Sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/) I found that
$\texttt{EllipticK[1 - m]/EllipticK[m] + O[m]^2 // Simplify}$ is
$-\log(m/16)/\pi - \frac{m}{2\pi}+O(m)^2.$

Answer (score 1):

Here is what Whittaker and Watson tell us in their classic text *A Course of Modern Analysis*.

---

The parameter $m$ in your question is usually denoted by $k^2$ so that $k\in(0,1)$ and $k=\sqrt{m}$ and further let $k'=\sqrt{1-m}$. Set $$2h=\frac{1-\sqrt{k'}}{1+\sqrt{k'}}\tag{1}$$ so that $0<h<1/2$ and then we have the series $$q=h+2h^5+15h^9+150h^{13}+O(h^{17})\tag {2}$$ The ratio $K'/K$ is now given as $$\frac{K'} {K} =-\frac{1}{\pi}\log q\tag{3}$$

Comment: Thanks!, could you give a page number please?

Comment: @DonFuchs: it's available on Page 486 chapter XXI